# Add text to a line in OmniGraffle

Tags: text, omnigraffle

If I have a line or arrow connecting two objects, how do I get a piece of descriptive text attached to that line? If I move the line, the text should follow.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at: [Adding Labels to the Connecting Lines](https://support.omnigroup.com/documentation/omnigraffle/mac/7.8/en/diagramming-basics/#adding-labels-to-the-connecting-lines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Option + Double-click

Hold [Option/ALT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_key) while double-clicking on the line to add a label to it.

If this maneuver instead creates a point to adjust the line from, double-click without Option/ALT. You can swap between Option/ALT-double-click (a) creating a point and (b) creating a label via a setting in `Preferences → Drawing Tools → Line Editing`.

Also, [the documentation mentions](https://support.omnigroup.com/documentation/omnigraffle/mac/7.8/en/diagramming-basics/#adding-labels-to-the-connecting-lines) clicking on the line while using the Text tool.

Comment: Worked, thanks. Tip: After adding text, you can drag the text along the line to change its position.